# How to make a generic function with the arguments of the same type using Flow generics

Tags: javascript, generics, flowtype

I am trying to make a typed wrapper around lodash's `isEqual` function. I want it to work only for two arguments of the same type. I have following code:

```
export function isEqual<T>(a: T, b: T): boolean {
  return _.isEqual(a, b); 
}

const c: boolean = isEqual('one', 2); // shouldn't it be a type error here?
console.log(c)
```

But it doesn't work, because it's possible to pass two arguments of different types to it and Flow is fine with that. What is a right way to implement such a function?

I am using Flow version 0.58.0

Comment: It shouldn't work for another reason: When `T` can be any type, there is no single function that can check equality for all possible types in a meaningful manner (unless you are willing to rely on reference equality in most cases). You'd need an overloaded equality function and the type system would have to provide the guarantee that an instance of this function exists for a specific type. This kind of polymorphism is usually called bounded polymorphism.

Comment: @ftor Yes, you are right, is't not really possible to define equality function with the signature I use. But this is not really what I am asking about. I need to define a function with two arguments of the same type. Lets suppose, for simplicity, that I need reference equality (so the body of function would be `a === b`). How can I define it?

Comment: I'd expect that `T` is unified to a single type, just like you. This is usually a trivial problem. I don't know why it is so hard with flow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little research I can explain what causes this behavior. `T` is implicitly expanded to the union type `isEqual<string|number>(a: string|number, b: string:number)`. I can't tell you why, but it is described on [github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3424#issuecomment-282581334).

From the example in the github comment above, I extracted a solution (or rather a hack) by using a phantom type `P`:

```
type __R<T, T> = T;
type _R<T> = __R<*, T>;

type _Eq<T, U: _R<T>> = (T, U) => boolean;
type Eq<P> = _Eq<*, *>;

const eq:Eq<any> = (a, b) => a === b;

eq(true, false); // type checks

eq(1, 2); // type checks

eq(true, "foo"); // doesn't type check
```

[Try it](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBA+jBKAeAKgGisgfFAvBg3AFCiSxJa6wKIBU6WRx40MAogI4roCqAXGSkzY8ACjRRuASlzYARgHt5AGwgBDAHZES0DogAKw2LrpQamRgGN56gM7AoEdr10aQhkavSzpObKtw4eLKMjiLAAE4ArhDoAGaqSjYQkiHsIgCM6ABMKYSEoRHR6ABEsYrFKUA).

There is probably a less messy solution but it is still a pity that flow doesn't just unify type variables with the same name and within the same scope with the same type.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I am not sure if I am going to use this solution, it looks too complicated, but it seems to solve my problem.